# Is there a way to mark a git commit to prevent pushing (even across merge/cherry-pick)?

Tags: git

I'm using a proprietary Real-Time OS, and occasionally I need to install and build that OS's kernel from sources (usually for debugging weird kernel interactions).  This code is secret, and I'm under contractual obligations to prevent it's release.  I'd like to be able to commit the code to a local branch but mark that commit (or possibly that branch) in such a way that I'd have to do something out of the ordinary to push, merge, or cherry-pick it.

Essentially I'm looking for a way to mark a specific commit as a poison pill: once it's added to a branch that branch will no longer push to a remote without special efforts.  Is this possible?  It seems a common enough use case ("here's my personal debug hackery...boy would it be embarrassing if I pushed that mess") that someone might have implemented such a behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a pre-push hook -- in fact, if you look in your .git/hooks directory on a repo that was created with a recent version of git, you should see a "pre-push.sample" shell script -- if you rename that as "pre-push", it will get run on every `git push` and refuse to push if any commit message starts with the string "WIP".  Its a pretty simple script with good comments about what it is doing and how to write other pre-push tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can't tie defaults to whether a commit is in your tip history that way, but you can set a branch's upstream to something in in your local repository so pushing just rehangs a local label, and you can break pushes to a remote, and you can script anything you want, make `git merge-base --is-ancestor thatcommmit HEAD || git push` a shell alias for instance.